# Find the transpose of the linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to find the transpose $f^{*}$ of the linear map $f: \mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{3}: (x,y,z) \mapsto (x+iy-iz,(3+2i)x+y,(2-5i)y+3z)$. Now $f^{*}$ is given by $f^{*}:( \mathbb{C}^{3} )^{*}\rightarrow ( \mathbb{C}^{3})^{*}:l\mapsto f^{*}(l)=l \circ f$ but I don't know how to go on from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3$ the dual basis to the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$. That is, $\varphi_1(x,y,z) = x$ and so on. Then

$$ (f^{*}(\varphi_1))(x,y,z) = \varphi_1(f(x,y,z)) = x + iy - iz $$

for all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ and so

$$ f^{*}(\varphi_1) = \varphi_1 + i \varphi_2 - i \varphi_3. $$

Similarly you can compute $f^{*}(\varphi_2), f^{*}(\varphi_3)$. Alternatively, if you represent $f$ by a matrix $A$ with respect to the standard basis then $f^{*}$ will be represented by $A^T$ with respect to the dual basis.

Comment: Thank you for giving two insights on the problem! I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:First step is to write $f$ in form of matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}X \\Y\\Z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 & i & -i \\3+2i & 1 & 0 \\0 &2-5i &3\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\\z \end{bmatrix}  $$ now you have linear amp as matrix . can you go on ?

Comment: Then the transpose of this matrix denotes the matrix of $f^{*}$ with respect to the dual basis. Thank you Sir!